# Possible bug in Pd patch

Tags: puredata

I have made a very simple patch, by which when a bang is triggered, it is meant to trigger a unique number between 0-2, in other words, no numbers are repeated.

In the way that I set it up, it is meant to work in theory. Even my programming mentor said that it should work, in theory, and he's generally a very smart man. He's informally known as being the boffin of the academy.

A few more details:

This happens in both purr data and pure data, with the exact same setup.

There are no external libraries are used. Just plain Vanilla objects.

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to attach the actual file itself, I will instead post an image of the code:

[image: Meow]

Comment: it would be much appreciated if the screenshot of the patch contained only the problematic patch and less empty canvas and black borders :-)

Comment: in general, it would also help to state the actual problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with depth-first processing (as used by Pd) and the related stack-unrolling, as this might lead to setting the 2nd input of `[select]` to an old value (which you didn't expect).

### Example

Note: `select:in0` means the left-most inlet of `[select]`,... The numbers generated by `[random]` are shown in bold (**`1`**) and the numbers output the patch are shown in bold italics (e.g. ***`3`***)

Imagine the `[select]` is initialized to `0` and the `[random 3]` object outputs a list **`2 0 0 2 0 2 ...`** (hint: `[seed 96(`).

The expected output would be ***`2 0 2 0 2 ...`***, however the output really is ***`2 0 2 2 2 ...`***

Now this is what happens if you consecutively send `[bang(` to the random generator:

1. `random` generates **`2`**

   - `2` is sent to the `sel:in0`, which compares it to `0` (no match)

     - and sends it out of `sel:out1` (the reject outlet), displaying the number ***`2`***
   - after that the number is sent to `sel:in1`, setting it's internal state to `2`.
2. `random` generates **`0`**

   - `0` is sent to the `sel:in0`, which compares it to `2` (no match)

     - and sends it out of `sel:out1`, displaying the number ***`0`***
   - after that the number is sent to `sel:1`, setting it's internal state to `0`.
3. `random` generates **`0`**

   - `0` is sent to the `sel:in0`, which compares it to `0` (match!)

     - and sends a bang through `sel:out0` (the match outlet)

       - triggering a new call to `random`, which now generates **`2`**
       - `2` is sent to the `sel:in0`, which compares it to `0` (no match)

         - and sends it out of `sel:out1`, displaying the number ***`2`***
       - after that the number is sent to `sel:1`, setting it's internal state to `2`.
   - after that the number `0` (still pending in the `trigger:out0`) is sent to `sel:1`, setting it's internal state to `0`!!!
4. `random` generates **`0`**

   - `0` is sent to the `sel:in0`, which compares it to `0` (match!)

     - and sends a bang through `sel:out0`

       - triggering a new call to `random`, which now generates **`2`**
       - `2` is sent to the `sel:in0`, which compares it to `0`

         - and sends it out of `sel:out1`, displaying the number ***`2`***
       - after that the number is sent to `sel:1`, setting it's internal state to `2`.
   - after that the number `0` (still pending in the `trigger:out0`) is sent to `sel:1`, setting it's internal state to `0`!!!

As you can see, at the end of #3 the internal state of `[select]` is `0`, even though the last number generated by `[random]` was `2` (because the left-most outlet of `[trigger]` will only send to `0` *after* it has sent the `2`, due to stack-unrolling).

### Solution

The solution is simple: make sure that the state of `[select]` contains the last displayed value, rather than the last one generated on the stack. avoid feedback when modifying the internal state.

E.g (using local send/receive to for nicer ASCII-art)

```
[r $0-again]
|
[bang(
|
[random 3]
|
|      [r $0-last]
|      |
[select]
|      |
|      [t f f]
|      |     |
|      |     [s $0-last]
|      |
|      [print]
|
[s $0-again]
```

Comment: Hey umläute, thanks very much for your help. Sorry I've taken so long to get back. I really appreciate the time you've put into this in helping me understand the stack unrolling, and I have a much better understanding of it now ^_^